# Access the object of appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to access the elements that are appended by a library that I use in my code, but I can't access them.  I have this line in my html.

```
<div class="bonds" id="original" style="display:block;"></div>
```

The library that I use will append some elements in here. So from the DOM inspector, it shows something like this.

```html
<div class="bonds" id="original" style="display:block;">
    <!-- append start -->
    <div class="FL-main fieldsLinker">
        <div class="FL-left">
            <select></select>
            <ul>
                <li data-offset="0"></li>
                <li data-offset="1"></li>
                <li data-offset="2"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- append ended -->
</div>
```

I'm trying to access the `<ul></ul>` element using the methods below but nothing works.

1. `$('#original').children().children().children();`
2. `var original = $('#original').find('ul');`

My goal is to append `<span class="icon-close"></span>` in each of `<li></li>` element when the page is loaded.

Comment: I would imagine that you're running your code too early, before the content is added to `#original`. What library are you using to add this content? What events does it allow you to hook to?

Comment: Ahhh now you mentioned it. Exactly like what you said, I'm running it before the library append those html. It's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `JQuery` find method to find the `ul` and loop over it's children.
Add your script at the end of all scripts. (library scripts).

```
$('#original').find('ul li').each(function(i) {
   $(this).append('<span class="icon-close"></span>');
});
```